# Is there a mechanism for asking questions that you are worried may get voted down or closed?

Tags: discussion, questions, allowed-topics

I would like to ask a question about calculating bonus points with Chase Freedom credit cards. It is certainly related to personal finance but it is pretty specific and doesn't seem like the type of question that is typically asked here. I worry it will get voted down and/or closed. Is there a way I can preview the question to make sure it is suitable first? Or should I just go ahead and ask?

Answer (score 3):

Just go ahead and ask.  I can't see why that would be a problem if it was reasonably well written.  Also, keep in mind that if you're not happy with how a question is received you can self delete.

Answer (score 1):

This is the type of question I usually don't vote to close, but will comment "did you read the fine print" or "did you contact the card issuer?"

If it does get closed, it will likely be the "too localized," a question regarding a product that a small fraction of readers would ever use. But as C Ross said, go for it.